# Issue deleting rows in SQL of type varchar

Tags: php

I am trying to create a form that will delete a row in a table based on the attribute a user selects from a drop down list of options. For some reason the first option, (attemptid) which is an int, works, but the other three (which are varchar) do not. The error handling I have set up to debug the script is returning `1` or `true`, but the row in question is not deleted.

HELP! I have tried everything but am only just learning PHP so imagine I am missing something quite simple.

```
require_once("settings.php");
$conn = @mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);
if ($conn) {
?>
   <form method="post" action="delete_attempts.php" name="delete_attempts" id="delete_attempts" >
      <label for="deleteby">
      <p>Select an option to delete results by:</p>
      </label>
      <select name="deleteby">
      <option value="attemptid">Attempt ID</option>
      <option value="firstname">First Name</option>
      <option value="lastname">Last Name</option>
      <option value="studentid">Student ID</option>
      </select>
      <p></p>
      <input type="text" name="delvalue" placeholder="Value">
      <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Delete Record" id="submit" />
      </div>
    </form>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST["delvalue"])) {
       // get value from form
       $delValue = trim($_POST["delvalue"]);
       echo $delValue;
        // queries to delete record
       $queryAttemptId = "DELETE FROM quizattempts WHERE attemptid = '$delValue'";
        $queryFirstName = "DELETE FROM quizattempts WHERE firstname = '$delValue'";
        $queryLastName = "DELETE FROM quizattempts WHERE lastname = '$delValue'";
        $queryStudentId = "DELETE FROM quizattempts WHERE studentid = '$delValue'";


       //select which value to search for
        if ($_POST["deleteby"] = "attemptid")   {
             // pass query to database
            $result   = mysqli_query($conn, $queryAttemptId);
        } // end delete attemptid
        else if ($_POST["deleteby"] = "firstname")   {
             // pass query to database
            $result   = mysqli_query($conn, $queryFirstName);
        } // end delete firstname
        else if ($_POST["deleteby"] = "lastname")   {
             // pass query to database
            $result   = mysqli_query($conn, $queryLastName);
        } // end delete lastname
        else if ($_POST["deleteby"] = "studentid")   {
             // pass query to database
            $result   = mysqli_query($conn, $queryStudentId);
        } // end delete student id

        echo  "this is the result $result";

        // if query is successful are found
        if ($result) {
            echo "<p>Delete operation successful</p>";
        } // end if result found
        else {
            // if no record is found in DB
            echo "<p>No records found</p>";
        } // end if no result found
    } //isset($_POST["attemptid"])
} //$conn

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        if ($_POST["deleteby"] = "attemptid")   {
```

That should be `==`.  Your code as written will assign `"attemptid"` to `$_POST["deleteby"]` and then return the same value...  which is always true.  So your other `else if`s are never even checked.

Also, your code as written is **vulnerable to SQL injection**.  You're already using mysqli; you should **strongly** consider using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Same thing goes for all other `else if` conditions. I just spotted that now.

Comment: Oh wow! I knew it was a rookie mistake, but I didn't think it would be so ridiculous!! Thank you.

Comment: We have only just started learning PHP and have not covered SQL injection yet, but I will look into prepared statements. Thanks.

Comment: there are a lot of security concerns on the web, and PHP does nothing to shield you from them.  (frameworks, both in PHP and in other languages, may help a bit.)  do _not_ deploy anything serious until you understand [everything on this list](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10) and how to defend against each.

Comment: also i am inclined to recommend you learn _anything but_ PHP for myriad reasons, but it sounds like you're a bit locked-in already  :)

Comment: I am just at the beginning of an IT course. I imagine we will cover security at some point, and I'll look at it myself over the coming break. I am beginning to see I have a lot more to learn than I orginally thought! What is it they say? The more you know, the more you know that you do not know...